# Can we define managed devices access to certain sites only

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, administration

Inside SharePoint online admin center, we can configure Unmanaged devices access:-

[image]

Where this will affect all the SharePoint sites. my question is if we can configure the unmanaged devices to certain sites only. for example the CEO site can only be accessed by managed devices while our entertainment site can be accessed by any device.. and so on.  is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to do this (must be SharePoint Admin):

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity "<SiteURL>" -ConditionalAccessPolicy AllowLimitedAccess
```

Note that if you limit access on unmanaged devices, users on managed devices must use one of the supported OS and browser combinations, or they will also have limited access.

Please read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices

Related: https://www.petervanderwoude.nl/post/accessing-sharepoint-and-onedrive-content-on-unmanaged-devices/